# Moshe Rabbeinu and Queen Esther's hesitation

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, purim, megillat-esther, yetziat-mitzrayim, egypt

The stories of Yetzias Mitzrayim and the story of Purim both feature a reluctant hero who initially hesitates to take action but ultimately steps forward to fulfill their role in the divine plan.

In the Purim story, Queen Esther is initially hesitant to follow Mordechais instruction to approach King Achashverosh. (Since she had not been directly summoned by the king).

Similarly, with the story of Egypt, Moshe expresses doubts and hesitations about Hashems instruction for him to request that Pharaoh release the jews, questioning his own speech impediment and lack of self-assurance.

What lessons can be derived from these specific situations of initial hesitation?

(Accepting unique and original answers, as well as explanations found in sefarim - please provide any relevant sources, with proper citation.)

Comment: I wouldn't draw any lesson.  Hesitation is never always good or always bad.  Moshe, Esther and Jonah hesitated but eventually did the right thing.  Others hesitated and concluded they should not go forward.

Comment: Maybe what you wrote is a lesson in itself 

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that sometimes, you should not hesitate too much ? See [Gittin 56a](https://www.sefaria.org/Gittin.56a.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he):

> אָמַר רַבִּי יוֹחָנָן עִנְוְותָנוּתוֹ שֶׁל רַבִּי זְכַרְיָה בֶּן אַבְקוּלָס הֶחְרִיבָה אֶת בֵּיתֵנוּ וְשָׂרְפָה אֶת הֵיכָלֵנוּ וְהִגְלִיתָנוּ מֵאַרְצֵנוּ

> Rabbi Yoḥanan says: The excessive humility *(in*  of Rabbi Zekharya ben Avkolas destroyed our Temple, burned our Sanctuary, and exiled us from our land

because he didn't want to sacrifice the calf with the Mum, nor to kill Bar Kamtsa.